# Prevent multiple users write on file at the same time

Tags: php, python, concurrency

I've done a php page `index.php` which uses some python scripts to retrieve some informations and copy them from a file **A** to a file **B**. My problem is that if I have more than one user that access `index.php`, **B** is modified from both the users. How can I make the second user wait until the first user has finished to modify **B**?

Comment: Take a look at the PHP documentation on `fopen` and files in general.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just want to say that the file is opened and written with python not with php.

Comment: Take a look at system semaphores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make one file in parallel `xyz.txt.in_use` and check for it every time from other location that the file is exists OR not then wait till it got deleted then after the writing completion, delete the `xyz.txt.in_use`, so that other can take charge on `xyz.txt`

Comment: I decided to accept this answer because it is simpler to implement, but also Eil1 AB's answer is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have that function called "CopyIt".

Then let's imagine that a user is requesting index.php to be executed. The simplest way to handle this request is like this scenario :

-First, index.php wants to call CopyIt,BUT! it doesn't call it directly to copy from A to B! index.php will put this request (copy things) into Cronjob and Operation System will execute it at a reserved time.

Now, for running this scenario, My suggestion is to:

1. Make a php file called : CopyAtoB.php
   [You will execute this file via php, later]
2. Write the whole function (codes) in CopyAtoB.php
3. Give a reserved time to every requests that index.php gets.
4. Schedule your reserved tasks with Cronjob file. (for more information about How to use a cronjob: 
   https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux)

GoodLuck

Comment: this answer is interesting, I want to give it a try. I'll let you know if it works (and then I'll accept the answer). Thanks

Comment: feel free. btw, cronjob is for linux users. If you use WindowsOS you can work with Windows Task Scheduler 
https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard